# How to write a case expression that calculates a specific date?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a case expression that calculates a person's RMD date (Required Minimum Distribution) i.e. pension related stuff. I'm using SQL Server 2012

Here is some criteria:

A participant reach's age 70½ on the date that is 6 calendar months after their 70th birthday.

If a participant was born before July 1, 1949, their RMD must happen by April 1st of the year following the calendar year in which they reach age 70½.

Example 1:  John’s 70th birthday is June 30, 2018.  He reaches age 70½ on December 30, 2018.  Under normal circumstances, his first RMD must be taken by April 1, 2019; however, since this client only makes distributions on March 1st of each year, John must take his first RMD (for 2018) by March 1, 2019.

---

If a participant was born after June 30, 1949, their RMD must happen by April 1st of the year following the calendar year in which they reach age 72.

Example 2:  John’s 70th birthday is July 1, 2019.  He reaches age 70½ on January 1, 2020., therefore, he is not required to take a minimum distribution until he reaches 72. He will reach age 72 on July 1, 2021. Under normal circumstances, his first RMD must be taken by April 1, 2022; however, since this client only makes distributions on March 1st, John must take his first RMD (for 2021) by March 1, 2022.

My goal is to write a case statement that when putting in their employee ID, gives me the RMD date.

```
--Birthdate before 7/1/1949
SELECT  BW_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, BIRTHDATE, CONTROLLED_GROUP_STATUS AS 'Employment Status', DATEDIFF(year,BIRTHDATE,GETDATE()) AS 'Current Age', DATEADD(month,6,BIRTHDATE) AS '6 months after Birthdate'
FROM    employee
WHERE BIRTHDATE < '7/1/1949'
```

Here is some sample data.
Note: Bw_ID = employee ID
[image]

This is a rough outline of what I'm hoping to see:

```
SELECT BW_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, 'RMD Date' = 
    CASE
        WHEN BIRTHDATE < '7/1/1949'     THEN 
        WHEN BIRTHDATE >= '7/1/1949'    THEN


FROM EMPLOYEE as E
```

Comment: This reads a lot like a home work question. What were your attempts, why didn't they work? Also, it's a `CASE` expression; T-SQL does not support `Case` (`Switch`) statements.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @Everett, Start by writing a query to get RMD based on the date of birth. Then we can see the table name and column names and so on.

Comment: Is july 1 the tipping point each year, or does it roll by month?

Comment: yes, July 1 is the tipping point. No, it doesn't roll by month